# Unable to run appium automation in different version of android devices

Tags: android, ui-automation

I am automating a mobile app. I have used the id to find elements in most of the cases. Wherever I did not find id's I have used XPath which is I have taken from Appium desktop application. But, This XPath is changing in a different version of the Android devices.

Can anyone assist me to solve this? I am struggling a lot here.

Comment: Can anybody suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

```
In such scenarios, here is what you can do
```

1. Find the xpath of the element on different android devices and declare them in page 
   object model.

   `@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//<xpath of the element>")`
    `private MobileElement element1;`

   `@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//<xpath of the element>")`
    `private MobileElement element2;`
2. You can write a helper function in Page object model class  which will tell you that 
   whether a particular element exists or not  on a screen.

   public boolean elementExist(Xpath xpath) {
           if (!appiumDriver.findElements(xpath).isEmpty()) {
               LOGGER.info("Element does exists");
               return true;
           } else {
               LOGGER.info("Element does not exists");
               return false;
           }
       }

Then, in the test case, you can do something like

```
if(elementExist(element1)) {
  click(element1);
} else if (elementExist(element2)) {
  click(element2);
}...
```

Comment: Hi Shrirang, Thanks for the quick replay. For your kind information, I am using the page object model. Still, I am facing this issue.